# Introduce character at specific line number

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Good day to all,

Today, I was wondering how to introduce **a** character at the end of specific line.

Intial line:  (The number corresponds to the line number. But, it is not part of the file)

```
...
101 ...
102 a,b,c,d
103 ...
...
```

Line what I want:

```
...
101 ...
102 a,b,c,d,
103 ...
...
```

Thanks in advance for any clue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'NR==102 {$0=$0","}1' file
```

This will add `,` at end of line `102`

Answer (score 6):

I think you want this:

```
sed '102s/$/fred/' file
```

That says "on line 102 replace the end of line with the word `fred`"